# What address to specify when mailing Form 1040 via FedEx

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, irs, form-1040

The IRS [website](https://www.irs.gov/filing/california-where-to-file-addresses-for-taxpayers-and-tax-professionals) suggests that when filing form 1040 I need to mail it to the following address:

**Department of the Treasury**
**Internal Revenue Service**
**Fresno, CA  93888-0002**

On the same page there is a link to [Private Delivery Services](https://www.irs.gov/filing/private-delivery-services-pds), which says that the IRS accepts mail from FedEx, DHL and UPS and at the very bottom tells to specify the following [addresses](https://www.irs.gov/filing/submission-processing-center-street-addresses-for-private-delivery-service-pds) when using FedEx/DHL/UPS. From there there is a California address that looks like this:

**Fresno - Internal Revenue Submission Processing Center**
**5045 East Butler Avenue**
**Fresno, CA 93727**

Here are my questions:

1. Does the Butler address in Fresno accept the form 1040?
2. If yes, do I have to specify **Department of the Treasury** in the Butler address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Butler Avenue address in Fresno accepts Form 1040.  From the [private delivery services address page](https://www.irs.gov/filing/submission-processing-center-street-addresses-for-private-delivery-service-pds):

> Private Delivery Services should deliver **returns**, extensions and payments to the following Submission Processing Center street addresses only:

(Emphasis Mine) Form 1040 is the form for tax returns.

You do not have to add anything to the address given on that page.  The address given is sufficient:

> **Fresno - Internal Revenue Submission Processing Center**, 5045 East Butler Avenue, Fresno, CA 93727

The reason for the different addresses whether you are mailing using the US Postal Service vs. private delivery services like FedEx is that the USPS mailing address goes to a Post Office Box.  Private delivery services cannot deliver to a Post Office Box.  The street address given is the street address that the Fresno IRS Center accepts deliveries to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One last question. The USPS addresses differ based on form types and whether you have enclosed a payment or not. Is the FedEx address universal for everything and then they do the sorting there themselves?

Comment: @Armani Yes, the address is for everything. According to the page, quoted above, “returns, extensions, and payments” can all be delivered to those addresses.